# How to tag platform related questions that include a code sample in a specific language?

Tags: discussion, tags, asking-questions

I would appreciate some advice on what are considered proper tags for questions that are platform specific (e.g. windows, linux, ...)  but not programming language specific.

Yesterday I posted this question: [How to prevent flushing to disk of a memory map opened on a windows temporary delete-on-close file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635860/how-to-prevent-flushing-to-disk-of-a-memory-map-opened-on-a-windows-temporary-de).

It relates to windows platform specific features that are not dependent on any specific programming language. To illustrate and allow reproducing the problem, I included sample code in c++.

Furthermore, in addition to the [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows) tag and tags most closely related to the specific issue, I tagged the question with both [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) and [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) language tags, because to me the question seemed to be the most relevant to the communities using those languages.

After being reprimanded by a high rep user not to "add irrelevant tags trying to get attention to your question", I included the [language-agnostic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-agnostic) tag.

However that seems to also be considered inappropriate by some, as my question was just now edited to remove this tag, with the following comment:

> Removing language-agnostic. This question is C++ specific (and Windows-platform specific)

I don't agree with this (including a c++ sample does not make the question itself c++ specific), and could revert the edit, but before doing so and to prevent potentially endless re-tagging edits, I thought it wiser to request your advice on what the community considers appropriate tags for platform specific, but language independent questions that include sample code in a specific programming language.

Comment: Well, first you want to reduce your code considerably. Most of it has nothing at all to do with reproducing your problem. Which would likely simplify it so much you have a chance to actually ask about the winapi involved without neccessarily tying it to a specific language.

Comment: @Deduplicator ok, fair point. I have reduced the sample code in my original question somewhat. That still leaves this question on what tags are appropriate unanswered though.